# A directory that is owned by some non-superuser, but can't be deleted by them

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, btrfs, xattr

Is it possible to create a directory that its owner can't delete? Let's say I have directory `bar` owned by user `foo`, and I'd like to create a subdirectory `bar/baz`, also owned by `foo`, such that:

- `foo` can create and remove files and directories in `bar/baz` as normal
- `foo` can create and remove files in `bar` as normal
- `foo` can remove most directories in `bar` as normal
- `foo` (or any other non-superuser) CANNOT remove the directory `bar/baz`

The reason I'd like to do this is because I'd like to set up `bar/baz` as a BTRFS subvolume (to exclude it from snapshots), and if `foo` can remove it and recreate it using `mkdir`, then it would not be a subvolume anymore.

Comment: Once you mount the subvolume on `baz` I don't think anybody can delete that directory - they'll be sent packing with a resource in use error or something like that.

Comment: @muru I don't believe this is true on recent enough versions of Linux. I can `rm -rf` a btrfs subvolume as a user if I own it and its parent dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least two ways to prevent an owner from deleting a directory.

- A directory can't be deleted if it isn't empty.  So put something in it the owner can't delete.

  - A directory they don't own
  - a file (owner doesn't matter) that is immutable
- Mount something on the directory

In the first case, they'd still be able to rename the directory.
But if something is mounted on it (which is what you want anyway), they can't do anything to it.  Now if they can *unmount* what is on it...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you want that anyway". I'm not trying to mount a btrfs subvolume into this directory -- it *is* a btrfs subvolume.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then.  BTW, it is common to touch a file in a directory (like ".keep") to prevent it from being deleted.   This will block `rmdir` but not `rm -rf` without the extra step of (root) making it immutable.

Comment: Indeed, `touch dir2/.keep && chattr +i dir2/.keep` (as root) seems to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Deletion of either files or directories, requires permission to the parent directory.

Therefore if you have directories of `/dir1/dir2`, contents of `dir2` do not matter, with the owner of `dir1` set to `user1`, and the owner of `dir2` set to `user2`, then `user2` will not be able to either delete or rename `dir2`, regardless of whether there are files in `dir2`. Just look at `/home`. No user can delete their own home directory because `root` owns `/home`.

Comment: But in my case, both `/dir1` and `/dir1/dir2` should be owned by `user1`.

Comment: Actually, it's not ownership that matters, but write access to both directories.  But it would be rare to own the directory and not have write... and less rare to not own it and have write.